# Does defult server still exist after I add a server block to http block?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My `nginx.conf` file doesn’t contain a `server` block inside the `http` block so I assume it uses a default server on port 80. However, I’ve been unable to find confirmation of this.

I’m wondering if I now add this `server` block inside my http block:

```
server { 
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
}
```

Does my assumed default server still exist or has my new server overridden it to now be the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide no default explicitly (using the "default_server" parameter in the listen directive) nginx will use either the server matching the one named in the Host: header of the request or, lacking that, the *first* one it finds in your config.

You can read more about how requests are handled by nginx here:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html